# How to get top records of subset?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

Say I have a table

```
StoreID   TotalSales   Month  Year
  --      ----------   -----  ----
  1         10           1    2012
  2         2            1    2012
  3         15           1    2012
  1         4            2    2012
  2         5            2    2012
```

I need: For each unique "Month/Year", grab the top two StoreID's with the highest Sales.

I'm at a loss on how to do this. I tried with a `cross apply` but that doesn't seem to work. This is all way over my head so hopefully someone can give me a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried `TOP`? Are you actually storing `Month` and `Year` in separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query uses `Common Table Expression` and `Window Function` to be able to get all the columns within the row. It works on `SQL Server 2005 and up`

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  StoreID, TotalSales , Month, Year,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Month, Year
                                ORDER BY TotalSales DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT  StoreID, TotalSales , Month, Year
FROM    records
WHERE   rn <= 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1254/3)

Comment: Wow! I'm utterly amazed. I did notice that if there are two records with the same TotalSales, that gets included in the resultSet as well. Any idea?

Comment: because I used `DENSE_RANK` which will rank including duplicates. If you don't want that, change it to `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: I looked up `DENSE_RANK()` on msdn and saw it mentioned that but couldn't find out what other options I had. You have no idea how much you just helped me. At least from here I have an idea of what to Google/Bing for. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. Seriously, you just saved me hours if not days of trying to piece that together. Thanks!

Comment: pheww...tried that myself but didnt realise about DENSE_RANK() +1 JW.